# VSCode auto changing directories immediately after running debug

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, terminal, directory, vscode-debugger

I am editing a file from a Github repository through the desktop app on VSCode and in the terminal I have the directory set to that of the repo that I am using (call it Project1). Whenever I attempt to debug the code from Project1, immediately after starting the debug, VSCode automatically switches to the directory of Project2, another project I am working on. The directory paths of project1 and project2 are also completely different (project2 is not stored on github) so I don't know why it's doing that. I have been working on project2 lately but I have also had the default directory preset to `Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop` whenever VSCode is opened for a period of time now. Any guidance appreciated

Comment: to be clear, the workspace folder you have initially opened **is** the Project1 directory?

Comment: @starball Yeah, when I am debugging it opens up a new terminal in the project2 directory. Not really a big issue tho, just kind of annoying when I try to run arguments in the terminal and I realize I'm in the wrong directory

Comment: 1) can you try to create a minimal project that reproduces this issue? 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: I can't really make a min reproducible code for this, I just press the debug button on the left side menu and it happens. I'll probably do an extension bisect to see if it fixes anything